# C++17 fold expression syntax?

Tags: c++, c++17, fold

I am trying to use compact fold expression without success.

For instance here is a **working** C++17 code

```
template <bool... B>
struct Fold_And : std::integral_constant<bool, (B && ...)>
{
};

template <bool... B>
constexpr auto Fold_And_v = Fold_And<B...>::value;


template <typename V, typename... Vs>
std::enable_if_t<
    Fold_And_v<std::is_floating_point_v<V>,
               std::is_floating_point_v<Vs>...> >
foo(const V& v, const Vs&...)
{
}
```

I want to translate it into a more compact form (not using the intermediate `Fold_And`)

```
template <typename V, typename... Vs>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<V> && ... &&
                 std::is_floating_point_v<Vs> >
foo_compact(const V& v, const Vs&...)
{
}
```

However, this is apparently illegal C++ as both g++ and clang++ compilers fail to compile it.

**My question**:

- is it only a syntax problem in `foo_compact()`? (what is the right one?)

Or

- fold expression can not be used directy with complex subexpressions and we can not do better than using the 2 steps approach (`foo()` code using the `Fold_And` struct)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You almost got it! Fold expressions *have* to be surrounded by parentheses:

```
template <typename V, typename... Vs>
std::enable_if_t<(std::is_floating_point_v<V> && ... &&
                 std::is_floating_point_v<Vs>)>
foo_compact(const V& v, const Vs&...)
{
}
```

Notice the parentheses after `<` and before the last `>`.

Comment: Argg... A beginner error! Thanks and sorry for the noise!

Comment: TIL fold expressions can be used as template arguments. A major "duh" moment for me.

Answer (score 6):

Fold expression requires parenthesis, so:

```
(std::is_floating_point_v<V> && ... && std::is_floating_point_v<Vs>)
```